# Limit of hyperbolic and trigonometric functions

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sinh x-\sin x}{x-\sin^2x}
$$

As initially it's in 0/0 form, I applied L'Hôpital's rule.

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cosh x-\cos x}{1-\sin2x}
$$

Now if I simply substitute $0$, then I get $0/1$ which is $0$. So is the answer $0$?

My book says answer is $1/3$.

Comment: $0$ is the right solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cosh(x)-\cos(x)}{1-2\sin(x)\cos(x)}=0$$